# What should be the ideal number of clusters for the plot whose image is given?

Tags: r, clustering

[image: Wssplot]

I have a dataset whose wssplot I've created but then not able to find any sharp elbow, so if anyone could please me with it?

Comment: We even don't have the context of this plot. And cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891855/what-should-be-the-ideal-number-of-clusters-for-this-wssplot

Comment: What do you want to do ? decide on the number of clusters in a cluster analysis ?

Comment: @fcop yes wanted to decided on the number of clusters

Answer (score 4):

### One cluster only

There is no substantial improvement in WCSS to be seen.

Note that the Y axis does not start at 0. Furthermore, WCSS is expected to decrease with the number of clusters. Even just assigning a single point to a new cluster obvioudly decreases WCSS, but foes not yield a better clustering. So **if you don't see a clear 'outlier' where the curve drops a lot and then abruptly stops dropping, then something did not work**.

Either this data set **does not have clusters**.

Or it was **not preprocessed well**, so that **the algorithm cannot detect them** (very common).

Try plotting and visualizing the data set. If you don't see clusters there, don't expect the clustering algorithm (in particular not k-means) to find any either. Don't use plots that *distort* axes. Use the same scale as your algorithm to "see the data the way the algorithm sees your data".

Comment: Although the question is pretty vague, still your answer does not describe *how* did you conclude from the plot that one cluster solution is preferable. The "how" question seems to be the - unstated directly - essence of the question.

Comment: I did: no substantial improvement of WSS. It just keeps on dropping smoothly, like it does on random uniform data. There is no k where the relative i provement is surprisingly big. WSS is expected to decrease with the number of clusters.

Comment: Copy-and-pasting this comment to answer would, imho, lead to substantial improvement in the answer as it seems to be direct answer to the question asked ;)